# Replace a string with another string longer than 255 chars. Type mismatch (error 13)

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I have a problem with excel. I inserted an image for reference.

I Need to replace the text in the D1 cell, where the text matches any of the id's in column A, and I need to replace that with the correspondent text contained in column B for each id.

[image: This is how my excel sheet looks like]

I have a code to replace the id's in the D1 cell, but the problem is that some of the text exceeds the 255 characters and it gives me a "Type mismatch (Error 13)" error. The code looks something like this:

```
Sub ReplaceText()

For i = 2 To LastRow

    id = Range("A" & i).Value
    textToReplace = Range("B" & i).Value

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("D:Z").Replace What:=id, Replacement:=textToReplace, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False

Next i

End Sub
```

I would like to know if there is something I can do to be able to insert text longer than 255 characters.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To work around this, replace your strings in segments of < 256 characters, like this

```
Option Explicit ' first line in Module

Sub ReplaceText()
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim ID As String, TextToReplace As String, Text As String
    Dim Mark As String, MaxLen As Long
    Dim SearchRange As Range

    MaxLen = 200
    ' Choose a character for Mark that is not in your data, 
    '  and is not a special char: ~?*
    Mark = "@" 
    lastRow = 6 ' set this to suit
    Set SearchRange = Worksheets("Sheet3").Columns("D:Z")

    For i = 2 To lastRow
        ID = Range("A" & i).Value
        TextToReplace = Range("B" & i).Value
        If ID <> vbNullString Then
            Do
                Text = Left$(TextToReplace, MaxLen) & Mark
                ' Terminate the loop when all of TextToReplace has been processed
                If Text = Mark Then Text = vbNullString
                TextToReplace = Mid$(TextToReplace, MaxLen + 1)
                SearchRange.Replace _
                  What:=ID, _
                  Replacement:=Text, _
                  LookAt:=xlPart, _
                  SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                  MatchCase:=False, _
                  SearchFormat:=False, _
                  ReplaceFormat:=False
                ID = Mark 
            Loop Until Text = vbNullString
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I tried the way you sugested, but unfortunately, it still gives me the same error when it encounters a string longer than 255 characters, I´m not sure what is wrong.

Comment: Oh no, Sorry, my bad, it does work, I had a small typo.

Thank you very much!

Comment: This algorithm is bogus! What if the 200 barrier cuts half the ID?
"...minim ""TEX" | "T 5"" veniam..."